# How to split and ignore separators in file path string using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I have a string like this

```
LASTSCAN:C:\Users\Bob\Scripts\VisualizeData\doc\placeholder.PNG:1557883221.11
```

The format of the string is `[Command][File path][Timestamp]`. Currently it is separated by colons but the file path also has a colon. Other times the format of the string may change but it is always separated by a colon. For instance:

```
SCAN:2000:25:-12.5:12.5:C:\Users\Potato\potato.PNG:1557884143.93
```

This string has a signature of `[Command][Frames][Speed][Start][Stop][File path][Timestamp]`

How do I split the input string to obtain a output like this?

```
['LASTSCAN', 'C:\Users\Bob\Scripts\VisualizeData\doc\placeholder.PNG', '1557883221.11']
```

Expected output for 2nd example

```
['SCAN', '2000', '25', '-12.5', '12.5', 'C:\Users\Potato\potato.PNG', '1557884143.93']
```

Comment: is the C:\ always the only part of the path with allowable colons? Also, FWIW these are colons (:) and not semicolons (;).

Comment: Yes, only the file path part of the string has allowable colons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try splitting on the regex pattern `:(?!\\)`:

```
input = "LASTSCAN:C:\Users\Bob\Scripts\VisualizeData\doc\placeholder.PNG:1557883221.11"
output = re.split(r':(?!\\)', input)
print(output)

['LASTSCAN', 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\Scripts\\VisualizeData\\doc\\placeholder.PNG', '1557883221.11']
```

The logic is to split on any colon which is *not* immediately followed by a path separator.  This spares the `:` in the file path from being targeted as a point for splitting.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be certain the ":" you wish to keep is immediately followed by a "\" and that there will be no other "\" around. You could try something like this.

```
new = string.split(':')
for i in range(new):
    if new[i][0] == "\":
        new[i-1] += new.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using regex:

```
import re
s = 'SCAN:2000:25:-12.5:12.5:C:/Users/Potato/potato.PNG:1557884143.93'
print(re.split(':(?!/)',s))
```

Output:

```
['SCAN', '2000', '25', '-12.5', '12.5', 'C:/Users/Potato/potato.PNG', '1557884143.93']
```

Also, at least for me, you have to change `\` to `/`, and in the regex expression as well.